# Summary Links Web Part spacing

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, hyperlink, summary

I'm using Summary Links web part in our SP2010 pages. However, I would like to edit the spaces that it places before each list item:

[image: Summary Link Web Part]

When I looked at the source code, I saw that the UL tag was using this class: dfwp-list. I tried modifying it via a custom CSS code:

[image: Custom CSS code]

But it's not doing the desired effect :( Do you know of any way that I can get the desired effect?

**Update:**

Here's what I see in the developer tool:

[image: Developer Tool]

Comment: Have you inspected the element in your browser? Your style might be out-weighted by a more specific rule. In IE press F12, in Chrome right click > Inspect element, in Firefox you need firebug (same method as Chrome to inspect)

Comment: @Stecman Thanks for the reply :) I've added a screenshot above on what I see in the developer tool of IE. I'm new to this, BTW, so all help is truly appreciated :(

Comment: With that element selected, have a look in the "Style" pane to the right (you can see the edge of it in your image) - if your style is crossed out in there, see what below it in the list is overriding it. Your selector `.dfwp-list` will need to be at least as specific as the one that's overriding it. eg `.someclass .dfwp-list` would out weigh `.dfwp-list` because it is more specific.

Comment: @Stecman Yey! ok got it! problem solved! Yes, there was another global CSS that was overriding mine :) Thank you so much :)